# pandas groupby how to aggregate on a column and convert to a matrix that each cell is a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a `df`,

```
key    amount    code    year_month
CHQ    100       1000    201701
EFT    200       1000    201701
CHQ    300       2000    201702
CHQ    400       2000    201702
EFT    500       3000    201703
EFT    600       4000    201703
```

I like to `groupby` `code` and `year_month`, and then aggregate count on `key` in a dictionary, so the result looks like

```
                   key
code year_month
1000 201701        {'CHQ':1, 'EFT':1}
2000 201702        {'CHQ':2, 'EFT':0}
3000 201703        {'CHQ':0, 'EFT':2}
```

and then transform the above `df` into a matrix with `code` values as row labels, and `year_month` values as column labels, and also do aggregation on row 0 and column 0, that e.g. `(1,1)` sums `count` for all `code` and `year_month`, `(1,2)` sums the `count` for `201701`.

```
     0          1                  2                      3                 4 
 0   -1         0                201701                 201702            201703
 1   0    {'CHQ':3,'EFT':3}  {'CHQ':1,'EFT':1}    {'CHQ':2,'EFT':0}  {'CHQ':0,'EFT':2}              
 2   1000 {'CHQ':1,'EFT':1}  {'CHQ':1,'EFT':1}    {'CHQ':0,'EFT':0}  {'CHQ':0,'EFT':0}                    
 3   2000 {'CHQ':2,'EFT':0}  {'CHQ':0,'EFT':0}    {'CHQ':2,'EFT':0}  {'CHQ':0,'EFT':0}
 4   3000 {'CHQ':0,'EFT':2}  {'CHQ':0,'EFT':0}    {'CHQ':0,'EFT':0}  {'CHQ':0,'EFT':2}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you would want to do this? Dictionaries aren't the best to work with, for one, and two, having that 0 count in those dicts is not going to be simple.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ coz it is easier for the UI to pick up a value by selecting a `code/year_month` combo and read the dict to display the value

Comment: Using your own result with `unstack`, I have the same question why we need dict here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = dict.fromkeys(df.key.unique(), 0)
b = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:a))

for t in df.itertuples():
    b[t.year_month][t.code][t.key] += 1
    b['All'][t.code][t.key] += 1
    b[t.year_month]['All'][t.key] += 1

idx = df.code.unique().tolist() + ['All']
idx = pd.CategoricalIndex(idx, idx, ordered=True)

col = df.year_month.unique().tolist() + ['All']
col = pd.CategoricalIndex(col, col, ordered=True)

m = pd.DataFrame(b, idx, col)
m = m.mask(m.isna(), a)

m

                    201701                201702                201703                   All
1000  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}
2000  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}
3000  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}
4000  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}
All   {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}  {'CHQ': 9, 'EFT': 9}
```

---

### Sums with `append` and `concat`

```
d = df.groupby(['code', 'year_month', 'key']).size().unstack([1, 2], fill_value=0)
d = d.reindex(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(d.columns.levels), fill_value=0)

def add_level(d, k):
    return pd.concat([d], keys=[k], axis=1)

m = d.join(d.sum(1, level=1).pipe(add_level, k='All')).pipe(
    lambda d: d.append(d.sum().rename('All'))
)

m.groupby(axis=1, level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.xs(x.name, 1).to_dict('i')))

                    201701                201702                201703                   All
1000  {'CHQ': 1, 'EFT': 1}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 1, 'EFT': 1}
2000  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 2, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 2, 'EFT': 0}
3000  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 1}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 1}
4000  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 1}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 1}
All   {'CHQ': 1, 'EFT': 1}  {'CHQ': 2, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 2}  {'CHQ': 3, 'EFT': 3}
```

---

Alternate `to_dict`

```
pd.DataFrame({
    j: {
        i: m.loc[i, j].to_dict()
        for i in m.index
    } for j in m.columns.levels[0]
})
```

### Old Answer

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

d = df.groupby(['code', 'year_month', 'key']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).assign(
    key=lambda d: d.to_dict('r')
)[['key']].reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1).assign(key=lambda d: list(map(Counter, d.key)))
d

   code  year_month                   key
0  1000      201701  {'CHQ': 1, 'EFT': 1}
1  2000      201702  {'CHQ': 2, 'EFT': 0}
2  3000      201703  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 1}
3  4000      201703  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 1}
```

Then

```
fv = Counter(dict.fromkeys(df.key.unique(), 0))
d2 = d.pivot_table(
    'key', 'code', 'year_month', 'sum',
    margins=True
).pipe(lambda d: d.mask(d.isna(), fv))
d2

year_month                201701                201702                201703                   All
code                                                                                              
1000        {'CHQ': 1, 'EFT': 1}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 1, 'EFT': 1}
2000        {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 2, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 2, 'EFT': 0}
3000        {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 1}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 1}
4000        {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 1}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 1}
All         {'CHQ': 1, 'EFT': 1}  {'CHQ': 2, 'EFT': 0}            {'EFT': 2}  {'CHQ': 3, 'EFT': 3}
```

---

We can hack some stuff to get things to work.  I don't feel good about this but maybe it's enough to get you what you need.

Use `Counter.update` to alter objects inplace

```
d2.applymap(lambda x: x.update(fv));

d2

year_month                201701                201702                201703                   All
code                                                                                              
1000        {'CHQ': 1, 'EFT': 1}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 1, 'EFT': 1}
2000        {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 2, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 2, 'EFT': 0}
3000        {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 1}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 1}
4000        {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 0}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 1}  {'CHQ': 0, 'EFT': 1}
All         {'CHQ': 1, 'EFT': 1}  {'CHQ': 2, 'EFT': 0}  {'EFT': 2, 'CHQ': 0}  {'CHQ': 3, 'EFT': 3}
```

Comment: that is a brilliant solution, thx. In the matrix, there are some cell values that not enumerate all `key` values as keys, like `(ALL,201703)`, `{'EFL':2}`, is it possible to make it like `{'CHQ':0, 'EFL':2}`?

Comment: I'm sure there is.  I haven't tortured it enough yet.  Try adding `fv` again.

Comment: what do you mean by adding `fv` again?

Comment: In the answer, I created `fv` which represents a `Counter` object with zeros.

Comment: I mean in `pivot_table`, the `sum` aggregation should sum `(1000,201703), (2000,201703),(3000,201703),(4000,201703)` to `{'CHQ':0,'EFT':2}`instead of `{'EFT':2}`, I am wondering how to achieve that

Comment: i am getting a df with all `None` as values after `applymap`

Comment: That's why it's hacky.  It alters the original dataframe.  The return from the `applymap` is useless.  Mind you, I don't recommend this in production.  Just giving you information to figure something out on your own.  If I get a chance, I'll write something better.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my take if I got that right:

```
df_tmp = (df.groupby(['code', 'year_month'])['key']
           .agg(lambda x: (Counter(x),))
           .to_frame()
           .reset_index()
          )

# Pivot 
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df_tmp, index='code', columns='year_month', values='key', aggfunc=np.sum)
# Filling the gaps
df_final = df_pivot.apply(lambda x: [v[0] if v is not None else Counter(dict.fromkeys(df.key, 0)) for v in x ])
```

Note that this tupeling "`(Counter(x),)`" in the `agg` function is a little workaround since pandas doesn't seem to like working with objects. However, this is going to be unwrapped in the final `apply` call anyway.

Since you have `Counter` instances you can to things like summing over columns/rows and get the correct result:

```
df_final.sum(1)
```

---

### Copy & paste example

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from collections import Counter

data = """
key    amount    code    year_month
CHQ    100       1000    201701
EFT    200       1000    201701
EFT    200       1000    201702
EFT    200       1000    201702
EFT    200       1000    201702
EFT    200       1000    201702
EFT    200       1000    201702
CHQ    300       2000    201702
CHQ    400       2000    201702
EFT    500       3000    201703
EFT    600       4000    201703
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df_tmp = (df.groupby(['code', 'year_month'])['key']
           .agg(lambda x: (Counter(x),))
           .to_frame()
           .reset_index()
          )

# Pivot 
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df_tmp, index='code', columns='year_month', values='key', aggfunc=np.sum)
# Filling in the gaps 
df_final = df_pivot.apply(lambda x: [v[0] if v is not None else Counter(dict.fromkeys(df.key, 0)) for v in x ])
```